# Full privacy and Full speed with OpenVPN and OpenWRT?

Tags: routing, openvpn, privacy, openwrt

I have a glinet OpenWRT Router using it with a OpenVPN connection with PureVPN. Unfortunately the OpenVPN needs a lot of CPU and the router is only capable to serve 12Mbs. 
In order to use my full bandwidth of 30Mbs I would like to setup a selective routing which still allows full privacy in front of the ISP which has the best connection but also a binding to the state...

Does anybody has suggestions besides buying better hardware? ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://support.purevpn.com/does-purevpn-offer-multi-account-support) PureVPN supports multiple connections, so you could just set it up on every device separately and connect via this router only devices that can't have VPN client on them (for example gaming consoles).

Comment: Well yes, but the devices on the LAN would loose connectivity to each other. :/

Comment: Oh really? In my VPN client i have option to block or unblock LAN connections so i didn't know.